# How to make divs clickable on a jQuery sliding menu

Tags: jquery, html, menu, sliding

I have a sliding div menu made with jQuery, but you have to click on the LINK within the Div in order to make it slide. Can anyone tell me how to make the div ITSELF clickable?

You can see the menu and code here: http://jsfiddle.net/WhfDc/

I've tried to use CSS to make the anchor cover the entire div and it works sometimes. Any idea whether this is correct or not?

Comment: I can click without problems, the problem is the expected result =P

Comment: check out my answer :) Remember to up vote all the answers that helped you and set one as accepted whenever possible :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is possible by attaching click event handler on the div instead of anchor element which is inside the div.

Also I would suggest you to use jQuery to attach event handler instead of inline event handler.

Working demo - http://jsfiddle.net/WhfDc/1/

Comment: hmmm thanks, it's working in jsfiddle but not live, any idea why?

Comment: @AlyssaMarieIsk - There is a js error on your page `slideonlyone is not defined`. Make sure you have copied the function.

Comment: you're right thanks! this is perfect. I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need all that Javascript.
You can just bind the menu click event (for all divs with .evtog classes), the handler hides the submenus that are visibles and shows the submenu.

Try this:

```
$(function() {
  $("div.evtog").click(function() {
    $("div[name=events]:visible").slideUp(600);
    $(this).next().slideDown(200);
  })
});​
```

Note the $() wrapping the function, this is needed because in order to bind the elements they must be on DOM. And this guarantees that the function will be executed when the DOM is ready.

Working example: [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SqG6e/3/)

More info:

[.click](http://api.jquery.com/click/)
[:visible](http://api.jquery.com/visible-selector/)
[.next](http://api.jquery.com/next/)
[.ready](http://api.jquery.com/ready/)

Comment: it works on jfiddle but not live, any idea why? http://worldoceansday.org/?page_id=1035

Comment: the problem is that you are binding the event before the menu is ready. And you need to remove the js call on the a element. I have edited my answer. Note the $(handler), as documented here: http://api.jquery.com/ready/